# Yii2 Login Only For One Page

Tags: yii2

I have been attempting to implement an OpenID log-in with Yii2 today, and for the most part it has worked. Below is code from my controller, with the action 'Register' running through, and outputting the user->identity->username, but when I, say, redirect this action back to any page on the site, the logged in user is essentially forgotten. I can return to my Register action and have the user logged in.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    public function actionRegister()
{
        require ('../views/site/steamauth/userInfo.php');

        $localId = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];

        $foundUser = User::findOne(['steamid' => $localId]);

        if(isset($foundUser))
        {

            Yii::$app->user->login($foundUser);

            var_dump($foundUser);

            echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username;

        } elseif(!isset($foundUser)) {

            $db = new User();
            $db->steamid = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
            $db->username = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];
            $db->visstate = $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'];
            $db->profile = $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'];
            $db->avs = $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];
            $db->avm = $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'];
            $db->avf = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];
            $db->persstate = $_SESSION['steam_personastate'];
            $db->save();

            $foundUser = User::findOne(['steamid' => $localId]);

            Yii::$app->user->login($foundUser);

            return $this->goHome();
        }

}
/**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. After scouring Stackoverflow I found it.

The standard model function findIdentity

```
return isset(self::$usrs[$id]) ? new static(self::$usrs[$id]) : null;
```

must be change to reflect the new table of

```
return User::findOne($id);
```